# AJAX function in Laravel not posting form data to controller

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I have a form in Laravel where users can buy products. I am trying to achieve this dynamically without a page refresh. I am able to call the AJAX function okay but it is not posting the data to the controller and I need help. Everything in the controller works absolutely fine, the data just isn't sending to it.

Here is the HTML form

```
<form class="buy-product-form" id="{{$product->id}}" action="/UoE/buy-product/{{$product->id}}" method="POST">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    <button class="pull-right btn btn-primary">BUY NOW</button>
                                </form>
```

Here is my AJAX function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('form.buy-product-form').on('submit', (function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var product_id = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).closest("form").attr('action'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {'id': product_id},
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function () {
                        window.alert(url);
                    }
                });
            }));
        });
```

Here is the first few lines in the controller

```
 public function buyProduct($university_code, $product_id){
        $player = Player::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
        $product = Product::where('id', $product_id)->first();
        $totalPrice = $product->quantity_available * $product->price;
```

Comment: are you getting any output in the console or debugbar?

Comment: Do you send a csrf token in your ajax files (in site meta for example)? the {{csrf_field()}} in your form isn't in your ajax post to your controller
see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: @jtwes I have just added the meta tag and the ajaxsetup function now as well. Unfortunately that still doesn't work.

Comment: hm. You should at least see something or get an error. add
error: function(response) {console.log(response) } and in success output the response to console, too.

Comment: I did get a Laravel verify CSRF token error yesterday, but I cannot recall what caused that as my ajax function didn't even have the URL or anything in it.

Comment: Also, I think `$('form.buy-product-form').on('submit', (function (e) {` should be a click event, not submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went through the headache of POSTing via AJAX in Laravel. I had similar code to yours and it wasn't working. Some of the changes I made:

`<form>` tag had no action.

```
<form id="contact-form" class="main-form">
```

`<button>` tag:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary submit-button" type="button">Submit</button>
```

AJAX Call:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".submit-button").click(function(e){            
        form_data = $("form").serialize()
        $.ajax({
            url: "/contact",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            success: function(data) 
            {
                if ($.isEmptyObject(data.error))
                {
                    handleSuccess(data.success);
                }
                else
                {
                    handleError(data.error);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a request object passed to your controller, but you have declared that it takes two parameters.
In the route, you only specify one parameter (`$product->id`).
Here's what the controller method should look like, from my guess: (edited)

```php
public function buyProduct(Request $request){
        $product_id=$request->id; //could also be $product_id=$request()->id;
    }
```

Access the `Request $request` object or `request()` helper to get to data posted to your controller.

the post url: `url: $(this).closest("form").attr('action')` already translates to `/UoE/buy-product/{{$product->id}}`, so there is already the `product->id`/`product_id` there.

my suggestion is to change your route to a most post-like route `/UoE/buy-product` and pass the data (product_id, and the csrf token)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('form.buy-product-form').on('submit', (function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var product_id = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");

                //doesn't matter which csrf, they're all the same
                var csrf=document.querySelector("input[name='_token']").getAttribute('value'); 

                $.ajax({
                    url: `/UoE/buy-product',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        'id': product_id,
                        '_token':csrf //pass CSRF
                    },
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function () {
                        window.alert(url);
                    }
                });
            }));
        });
```

Comment: All that I need to send is the product_id, the controller then handles everything for me. So if the product_id is already being passed in the URL action, then do I still need to use a Request object, and if so what goes in there?

Comment: Since you are doing a POST request, I assume that you are going to 'post' data to the server. For example, get the values of the fields of the form `.buy-product-form` and put those in the `data:{}` request body.

Since you only need the product_id, then there's no need to use the request object.     (I would however suggest using a `Route::post('/UoE/buy-product'))` and then putting the product_id in `data:{'id':product_id}`. Then you would access `function (Request $request){ $product_id=$request->id; }`) - but that's just my opinion! whichever way suits you haha

Comment: Okay thank you so much, I have got it to work now. I am now trying to do what you said, I want to remove the Product_id from the URL and only have it sent to the controller via AJAX function. But it won't work unless I do put it in the URL. I just want to make sure it doesn't get sent twice if you get what I'm saying.

Comment: Much welcome ser. I edited my answer above to be cleaner, maybe that will help? Good luck

Comment: I defintely understand what you are trying to get me to do. But my IDE says that /UoE/buy-product is an unresolved file or directory and the link is not working. Even though I have changed it in my routes.php file

Answer (score 0):

Your controller action is expecting 2 arguments `buyProduct($university_code, $product_id)`, but in form action you are only passing product ID.

Comment: the $university_code argument is redundant and isn't actually used in the controller. I'll delete it.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you can't submit the form, because your button isn't a submit button.

Comment: Yes it is. `button` elements are `type="submit"` by default.

Comment: *goes off to check that

Comment: Here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type